# Alternatives for hosting a simple Slack App (AWS is too expensive)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

I've been developing a small Slack application for my team. It's a very simple app to help organizing projects. I've written it in Python and used **AWS Lambda** (one of the Slack API [hosting recommendations](https://api.slack.com/docs/hosting)) to host it. As the usage of this app will be very incidental, I thought that AWS Free Tier could handle it for a while. But I was surprised to discover that, while Lambda has a free tier, I need to configure a **NAT Gateway** that costs $0.045 per hour to get anything useful out of it.

I'm very disappointed by this. I can't justify the costs of this NAT Gateway for such a small and simple application (that will be used by 5-10 people maximum, and only sometimes). Is there are workaround that I could use (I've heard about NAT instances)?

EDIT: I've created a NAT instance and tried using it with my app. Thing is, now Slack is throwing me a `Timeout Reached` error (since Slack expects a response within 3000ms before throwing this error). So, are NAT instances slower than NAT Gateways?

Comment: Yeah, you could set up a NAT Instance on an EC2 instance, using a T2.nano, for $0.0058/hour. But the better question is, are you sure you really need a NAT Gateway? I've only found a few use cases that really necessitate them.

Comment: How is slack communicating with the Lambda function? Are you going via API Gateway?

Comment: @JamieStarke I'm not sure if I need it, but since I need to acess other resources inside my VPC (such as RDS), I think I probably do.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm using [Slack Client](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) and deployed it using Zappa. I'm not sure if Zappa uses API Gateway...

Comment: Rather than using a `t2.micro` as a NAT, you might find it easier to just run your application on that instance. As another possibly, do you need to run your Lambda function inside the VPC?

Comment: @kdgregory I'm not sure. I think my Lambda function needs to be inside the VPC so I can acess RDS. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: you can't connect from a Lambda outside the VPC to an RDS instance inside because there's no way to configure a security group. I missed your point about connecting to RDS.

Comment: _BUT_, if you already have a VPC configured, are you sure that you don't already have a NAT? If you're using public/private subnets, then you need a NAT to be able to do things like software updates. That doesn't mean that you absolutely need one: you can bring up instances without one, and you can choose to create new instances rather than update old ones. You might also have all instances in a public subnet. But it's worth checking.

Comment: Otherwise, my comment about running your app on a `t2.micro` or `t2.nano` instance rather than Lambda still applies (personally, I've become a _lot_ less enamoured of Lambda as I continue to try to use it -- I've seen some great use cases for security and monitoring, not so many for applications).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NAT instances provide Internet connectivity for EC2 instances located in private subnets. NAT instances provide network address translation. NAT instances are not related to API Gateway nor Lambda functions.

[NAT Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html)

API Gateway does not have a cost per hour unless you configure caching, which probably is not necessary for your use case. More details are needed to be sure.

[API Caching](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html)

Note: You can call you Lambda functions directly from your Python code if you do not need all of the features of API Gateway.

[Boto3 Lambda.Client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html)

Comment: *"NAT instances are not related to API Gateway nor Lambda functions."* That's not entirely true, for Lambda functions.  If a Lambda function is deployed inside a VPC (so that it can access other resources within the VPC, such as RDS) and that function also requires Internet access for outbound requests it subsequently originates (e.g. for accessing 3rd party APIs or interacting with most AWS service APIs) then a NAT device (instance or gateway) is indeed required.  For many environments, a t2.nano as a NAT instance is quite satisfactory for this purpose.

Comment: Are those NAT Instances slower than NAT Gateways? Because I've created a NAT Instance and now I'm receiving timeout reached errors from Slack (that usually happens when Slack waits more than 3000ms for a response) and that wasn't happening with NAT Gateways.

Comment: NAT instances and NAT gateways should have similar performance with low to moderate network workloads. If you have high network bandwidth requirements go with NAT gateways which will autoscale. Note: NAT instances are basically old technology for Amazon. These were the solution a few years ago as NAT gateways did not exist. Now NAT gateways are the preferred solution. Second Question: If you are seeing 3,000 ms  response times from your NAT instance it is either overloaded or misconfigured.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've followed the tutorial at [NAT Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) to configure it. Any hints on how should I look for some misconfiguration?

Comment: Sorry, I use NAT Gateways instead. Why do you want the hassle of managing your NAT instance?

Comment: @JohnHanley Just because the price for NAT Gateways is very high. You said that API Gateway does not have a cost per hours, but I don't know how to do what I have to do without a NAT Gateway. My application consists of a Lambda function with all my code alongside an RDS server running MySQL, both on the same VPC.

Comment: @Vinicius - have you verified that your NAT is actually NATting? 3000ms seems like a network timeout to me. Bring up an instance inside the VPC and verify that you can get to the outside world from it.